# How do you delete rows specified from an object in oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex-5

I have a drop down box on a page in my oracle apex application, I'd like to use the drop down box which displays a company's data(company name) within the company table (which I have achieved); which the user can use to identify specifically what company they'd like to delete. I'd then like to use a button to delete the selected company, and that's what I cannot figure out.

So far I have got as far as using dynamic actions to delete every entry in the table.

Pseudo code for what I am trying to achieve:

```
SELECT COMPANY_ID FROM COMPANYLIST,
DELETE SELECTED;
```

Company list being the drop-down box name.

[image: Description of the button and the action]

[image]

Comment: 20 hrs. Does no one have an answer to this? @Dmitry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are just struggling with the delete statement?

It should be something like this.

```
DELETE FROM company
WHERE company_id = (SELECT company_id 
                    FROM companylist
                    WHERE upper(company_name) = upper(:P1_COMPANY_NAME) );
```

Replacing `company` with whatever your company table is called, and `:P1_COMPANY_NAME` with whatever your select list item is.

Comment: The ':' selects the element on the page? in my case the drop down box.

Comment: Where is says "delete from company" and "select company_id from companylist" did you not mean to write them both the same? company = companylist?

Comment: Yes : references the page item. If it is just one table then they will both be company list yes, I assumed two tables from reading your first post.

Comment: Can you post your select list query?

Comment: It's fine now, it seems to be working. I had trouble as I was using the code in a dynamic action, however using it instead in a process seemed to work for me.